# Putting VBScript code in dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, vbscript, dotnetnuke

I am not sure about this issue where I need to put a vbscript code (from asp file) and put it in a dotnetnuke ascx file. Our client's IT guy who did the code in vbscript, requires us to reuse his code to put it in our dotnetnuke ascx file (the container). the code is for login purpose. his code uses include to reference to the other vbscript file for other functions used.

Is this possible? without converting the vbscript or use the asp file in the iframe.

Hope you understood my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

VBScript does not just plug into dotnetnuke.  There is no way to answer your question further because there is not enough information.